# Shoud I add typescript-eslint/parser and plugin manually?

Tags: eslint, typescript-eslint

I made my project by create next app and my eslintrc is like this

```js
module.exports = {
  extends: [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "next/core-web-vitals",
  ],
  rules: {
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": "warn",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-inferrable-types": "warn",

    "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "error",
  },
};
```

In above setting, `plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended` extends `base` config, and `base`[code](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/src/configs/base.ts) config module has `parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser'` and `plugins: ['@typescript-eslint'],`.

But Getting Started guide in [docs](https://typescript-eslint.io/getting-started/#step-2-configuration) recommends like below.

```js
module.exports = {
  extends: ['eslint:recommended', 'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended'],
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  plugins: ['@typescript-eslint'],
  root: true,
};
```

Why do parser and plugins add again?

When the `npx eslint .` command is executed, the result with `parser` and `plugins` and the result without `parser` and `plugins` are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why do parser and plugins add again

No specific reason - it'll work with or without it.
It's a nice thing to have though because it means that your config order won't accidentally supply the incorrect parser.

For example imagine that you're using the `foo` plugin and it sets `parser: 'foo'`. If you have the configuration

```
{
  extends: ['plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended', 'plugin:foo/recommended']
}
```

Then your project will be parsed with the `foo` parser, not `@typescript-eslint/parser`!

But if you instead configured it the other way around

```
{
  extends: ['plugin:foo/recommended', 'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended']
}
```

Then your project will be parsed with the `@typescript-eslint/parser`, not the `foo` parser!

By setting it locally in your project's config you're overriding this so that you know exactly which parser is being used.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. There is advantage to explicit overridin! Although I am not using any third-party libraries other than `recommended`, I will need to use local parser and plugin in the future. Thank you again!